# Проблема с кодировкой Python. Некорректный вывод в терминал

Tags: python, linux, utf-8, atom

Я тут столкнулся проблемой. Терминал `Debian` выводит мне вот такой текст:

> [[('\xd0\x98\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2', '\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb8\xd1\x85\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb', '\xd0\x93\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x8c\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87'), '9685234', '+79533524896']]

Но в редакторе `Atome` при использовании плагина `script`, он выводит:

```
[[('Иванов', 'Михал', 'Григорьевич'), '9685234', '+79533524896']]
```

В начале файла у меня стоит:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Что я делаю не так?
P.S Гугл мне не помог. `pythone 3.X`

Код программы:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
people = []
p1 = [("Иванов", "Михал", "Григорьевич"), "9685234", "+79533524896"]
p2 = [("Никитины", "Надежда", "Юрьевна"), "1356846", "+79823647812"]
....
if p1 not in people:
   people.append(p1)
   print(people)
```

P.S. Английский текст выводится нормально.

Comment: Очевидно, у вас в объекте находятся байты, а питон выводит байты экранированными (поведение Atom возможно неправильное). Чтобы получить нормальный вывод, нужно преобразовать байты в символы. А как это сделать, в немалой степени завиит от того, откуда вы этот текст вообще взяли, а вы этого не рассказали

Comment: Кстати, строчка `#!python3.6 #coding: utf8` — ничего не значащий бред

Comment: У меня по шаблону для .py стоят такие строки: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` и `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`